# Lottery program - Need to compare 2 arrays for common values

Tags: compare, textfield

I'm creating a lottery system using NetBeans' GUI builder for a college assignment. This is the first time I've attempted GUIs so if this is a 'stupid question' I apologise.

When the user enters their 6 numbers (range of 1-47), they generate winning numbers. When the 'Compare Numbers' button is pressed, it tells the user how many numbers they got right.

For this, I've used an array of JTextFields for both the user's numbers and winning numbers.

When I try to print out the number of matched numbers, it's always 0. I printed the arrays and found that it wasn't printing the values, but the actual JTextField objects. So I changed it to .getText, which printed the values but will not compare the arrays.

```
public static int compareNumbers(JTextField[] userNumbersArray, JTextField[] winningNumbersArray){
    int matchedNumber = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < userNumbersArray.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < winningNumbersArray.length; x++) {
            if (winningNumbersArray[i]getText().equals(userNumbersArray[i].getText())) {
                matchedNumber++;
            }
        }
    }

    return matchedNumber;
}
```

I am getting the error at (winningNumbersArray[i]getText().equals(userNumbersArray[i].getText())). I've tried other ways to compare, all to no avail. This is telling me that JTextField cannot be converted to boolean.

Again forgive an ignorance of knowledge, I'm quite new to GUIs.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code snippet:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TFTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    JTextField a[] = new JTextField[]
    {
      new JTextField("1"),
      new JTextField("2"),
      new JTextField("3"),
      new JTextField("4"),
      new JTextField("5"),
      new JTextField("6")  
    };

    JTextField b[] = new JTextField[]
    {
      new JTextField("1"),
      new JTextField("2"),
      new JTextField("3"),
      new JTextField("4"),
      new JTextField("5"),
      new JTextField("7")  
   };


    int matchedNumber = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < b.length; x++) {
                if (a[i].getText().equals(b[x].getText())) {
                    matchedNumber++;
                }
            }
        }

    System.out.println(matchedNumber);
  }
}
```

I have noticed two issues with your code:
 1. Missing period before getText() at line

```
  if (winningNumbersArray[i]getText().equals(userNumbersArray[i].getText())) {
```

2. Iterating twice using i index instead of i and x.

Hope it helps a little.

Side note - iterating over both of arrays in order to check if value is present in both is not efficient however since your arrays are small it is acceptable.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking a look at this. It was a long day and completely overlooked this.

Comment: Oh my bad. New here. I think I accepted it. The tick under the rep?